# SAVEPOINT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I rollback to a savepoint ( which was done before a commit ) in **MySQL**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` statement only in the transaction.

In [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html) (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html) you find:

> All savepoints of the current transaction are deleted if you execute a COMMIT, or a ROLLBACK that does not name a savepoint.

So the answer to your question is: no.